# Python + Django + Celery has a very low publish speed

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery, djcelery

I am having serious problems with task publish speed and I am currently working on debugging it, I think it's problem with Celery settings.

I'm using Django, Celery and RabbitMQ. I have a simple task that sends emails. This task works, but it's very slow.

For example I want to execute 10000 simple 'test_print() tasks' in a loop I can't publish more than 23-24/s. Before it would easily publish 1000+/s. I am having this problem with completely EVERY task I have in the system. It might have happened since I moved my code to Djcelery (wrapped celery project with Django code) or something changed on the server (less possible option). Here are my settings. It's using rabbitmq server.

Settings:

```
CELERY_BROKER_POOL_LIMIT=0
CELERY_CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER=1
CELERY_BROKER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=20
CELERY_BROKER_CONNECTION_RETRY=True
CELERY_BROKER_CONNECTION_MAX_RETRIES=100
CELERY_BROKER_HEARTBEAT=10
CELERY_TASK_SEND_SENT_EVENT =True
CELERY_CELERYD_SEND_EVENTS  =True
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='rpc://'
CELERY_CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD=500
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'


CELERY_TASK_ROUTES= {
    'parse_x.*': {
        'queue': 'parse_x',
        'routing_key': 'parse_x',
        },...
}
```

tasks:

```
@shared_task(name="solicitor_tracker.test_print")
def test_print(i):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(0.1)


@shared_task(name="setup_queue.test_print_task_setup_queue",acks_late=False, 
autoretry_for=(Exception,), retry_backoff=True)
def redirection_check_setup_queue():
    for i in range(0,100000):
        test_print.apply_async([i],queue="lawsociety_parse")
```

Comment: are u sure this is not caused by this piece of code `time.sleep(0.1)`?

Comment: No, its just test task for debugging, its not execution time problem, but slow message publishing

Comment: but u just said that you are publishing 23/s? May be that is caused by that delay? And execution time finishes much earlier than last message is printed?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. The deadly setting was broker_pool_limit=0, it was resetting connections after publishing. After setting it to default(10) it went to 500-1000 per sec